# What does shift->somesub() do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have been reading this code for a while, and I am not able to figure it out. What does the following do?

```
sub shared  { shift->state(broadcast => @_) }
```

https://metacpan.org/source/GRAY/WebService-Google-Reader-0.21/lib/WebService/Google/Reader.pm#L72

Comment: Something undocumented. Operand order of evaluation isn't specified by Perl except for specific operators. Perl could evaluate `@_` before `shift`. The second snippet friedo posted does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 13):

In object-oriented Perl, a method's *invocant* (the thing upon which the method was called, either a class or an instance of a class) is passed into the subroutine as the first parameter.

The parameters to subroutines are found in the special array `@_`. `shift` removes the first element of an array and returns it. If you don't specify an explicit argument to `shift`, it works on `@_` by default.

The usual pattern for OO methods is to do stuff like

```
# foo method
sub foo { 
    my $self = shift;
    # do stuff to $self
    $self->othermethod;
}
```

What's going on here is they are just using a shortcut to avoid creating the variable `$self`, and calling the `state` method on the invocant as returned directly from `shift`. So your method is equivalent to:

```
sub shared { 
    my $self = shift;
    $self->state( broadcast => @_ );
}
```

Comment: The array on the right side of the fat comma is making me cringe.

Comment: Outside any subroutine, `shift` operates on `@ARGV`; that's probably not relevant here.